# How does one save the IoTHub connection string after provisioning using DPS

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am trying to create a DeviceClient using DPS and IoTHub but there does not seem to be any example of how one uses DPS to provision a device and then save the connection string such that subsequent connections are performed directly with the IoT Hub.

Have I misunderstood the purpose of the DPS ?  Is it not the intention that the provisioning process is a once off step and that the device would then save its connection string for subsequent use ?

None of the examples appear to illustrate that the device saves its connection string and uses that during subsequent startup.

Is the intention that a device will always use DPS when it reboots to get a connection to it's IoTHub ?

Is there any documentation from Microsoft that explains these concepts and the intended use in different device lifecycle scenarios.

EDIT:

Below is what I have found to work when using DPS.  You can use DPS for every connection but it it not necessary if you can cache the AssignedHub.

Does this look correct ?  It seems to work but there may be better ways.

```
private async Task<DeviceClient> SetupDeviceClientAsync(Parameters parameters, EventLog logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            DeviceClient deviceClient;
            switch (parameters.DeviceSecurityType.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                // First time if we have no cached connection string
                case "dps":
                    logger.WriteEntry($"Initializing via DPS");
                    DeviceRegistrationResult dpsRegistrationResult = await ProvisionDeviceAsync(parameters, cancellationToken);
                    logger.WriteEntry($"dpsRegistrationResult: {dpsRegistrationResult.DeviceId}, {dpsRegistrationResult.AssignedHub}");
                    var authMethod = new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(dpsRegistrationResult.DeviceId, parameters.DeviceSymmetricKey);
                    deviceClient = InitializeDeviceClient(dpsRegistrationResult.AssignedHub, authMethod);

                    connectionString = "HostName=" + dpsRegistrationResult.AssignedHub + ".azure-devices.net;DeviceId=" + parameters.DeviceId + ";SharedAccessKey=" + parameters.DeviceSymmetricKey;
                    // Save this for next time
                    SaveConnectionString($"{parameters.DeviceId}\n{dpsRegistrationResult.AssignedHub}");


                    break;

                // This does not work with DPS - don't use it in conjunction with DPS - use if for standalone IoTHub connections 
                case "connectionstring":
                    logger.WriteEntry($"Initializing via IoT hub connection string");
                    deviceClient = InitializeDeviceClient(parameters.PrimaryConnectionString);

                    break;

                // Use this for subsequent connections with the saved DeviceId, SymmetricKey and AssignedHub from "dps" provisioning
                case "hubinfo":
                    logger.WriteEntry($"Initializing via IoT hub info from DPS string");

                    deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(parameters.PrimaryConnectionString, new
                                                            DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(parameters.DeviceId, parameters.DeviceSymmetricKey), TransportType.Mqtt);

                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Unrecognized value for device provisioning received: {parameters.DeviceSecurityType}." +
                        $" It should be either \"dps\", \"hubinf\" or \"connectionString\" (case-insensitive).");
            }

            return deviceClient;
        }
```

Comment: In the context of provisioning IoT devices to their cloud solution, provisioning is a two part process:

The first part is establishing the initial connection between the device and the IoT solution by registering the device.
The second part is applying the proper configuration to the device based on the specific requirements of the solution it was registered to.

Comment: could you tell are you using c#(or)pyhon for  provisioning IoT devices

Comment: during  provisioning, we connect IoT Hub to DPS it creates a  device  and Sends a telemetry message

Comment: the device does not save its connection string for subsequent use.Instead, the device uses the device provisioning endpoint to get the connection string from the IoT hub

Comment: The device provisioning process is a one-time process, and the device does not need to use DPS when it reboots to get a connection to its IoT hub

Comment: Refer to this for Provision a simulated symmetric key [device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-symm-key?pivots=programming-language-csharp#prepare-your-development-environment)

Comment: give you sample sample with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provisioning through DPS *can* be a one-time process, but there are cases in which you want to contact DPS again regularly:

- You want to move the device to a different hub
- You're rotating keys

In most cases, you can try the connection string that was obtained in an earlier DPS provisioning. If that connection fails, you can contact DPS again to see if you get a new connection string.

It's described in [this paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-deploy-at-scale?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#devices-that-can-store-a-connection-string) of the docs. How you save the connection string will vary per use case. Because IoT devices are not as standardised as regular computing hardware, how you store the connection string will be different each time. There is a [C# sample though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-deploy-at-scale?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#reprovisioning-sample) that stores the provisioning result and contains logic to reprovision in case of an error.

Comment: Thanks I will look at the sample.  The world would be lost without you -  dozens of searches and the samples you link to don't come up.  There is only so much AI can do I guess.  Now I am trying to figure out why my writeable properly ACKs don't result in updated Twin properties in the back-end!  Will post another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

From Overview of Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning [Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps#registration-and-provisioning).

- Registering the device creates the initial connection between the IoT solution and the device.
- Applying the right configuration to the device in accordance with the demands of the solution it was registered to.

Provision a simulated symmetric key device to Microsoft Azure IoT [Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-symm-key?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

- The device does not save its connection string for subsequent use.Instead, the device uses the device provisioning endpoint to get the connection string from the IoT hub.
- The device provisioning process is a one-time process, and the device does not need to use DPS when it reboots to get a connection to its IoT hub
- code reference taken from Provision a simulated symmetric key device to Microsoft Azure IoT [Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-symm-key?pivots=programming-language-csharp#prepare-your-development-environment) .
- Create an IoT Hub and IoT device
- Create Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service
- Add IoT hub in (DPS) Linked IoT hubs.
- Manage enrollments with Add link to IoT hub.
- Enable IoT Edge on the provision device.
- Used this link for  `az iot dps enrollment-group`  from  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/dps/enrollment-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-dps-enrollment-group-compute-device-key).
- Replace the your resourcegroupname, dpsname,  [enrollment_id](https://i.imgur.com/w9kT2n9.png),  [registration_id](https://i.imgur.com/sQlXvaE.png). It gives  `derived-device-key`  or  `PROVISIONING_SYMMETRIC_KEY`.

  ```py
    az iot dps enrollment-group compute-device-key -g {resource-G-N} --dps-name {dpsname} --enrollment-id {enrollmentid} --registration-id {registrationid}
  ```

[image]